# Remove gap from img tag css

Tags: css

I have a Problems.

Allways when i iclude a img Tag in my HTML File, i have a Gap arround the Tag. It is not margin and not padding. I ask me what it is ?

Can anybody help me to delete the gab with css ?

```
<img src="../images/modules/Bildergalerie2.jpg" />
```

Thanks

---

```
    <img src="../images/modules/Bildergalerie2.jpg" />
```

Comment: please post your code...

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gap is caused by the fact that an <img> is an inline element which cause them to follow the same rules as text. To fix that, you could add display: block; on the image or play with vertical-align (Set it to bottom). For more information, read that excellent article at Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
img{border:none 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {display: block;}//removes the gap
```

Answer (score 0):

IMG tags are inline elements and are white-space dependent methods. The space around the IMG tag is actually based on the font-family you have selected for your site, what you can do is select the elemnt is css

```
img
{ 
    display: block;
}
```

But this will cause the  to break the line and move to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure, it is not a border with the same color as the background around?
- Make sure, it does not inherit margin oder padding from elsewhere
- Make sure, that in your css margin (and padding) for imgs is explicitly set to zero (because the deafault stylesheet of some browsers have a margin for img)
- Make sure, the gap is not part of the image (not so likely but possible!)
- Post Code here...